# Intellij Default SDK Unused Path Issue

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea

I try to set the default sdk to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`. It works fine, but when i open the project again it changes to a Python path which doesn't exist anymore. On Platform Settings SDKs there is not any Python path too.

How can i remove this path and let the Java JDK be the default sdk?

[image]

Edit: I think i found the problem, but i don't know how can i fix it. Here is a component of the project.default.xml file

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="Python 3.5.2 (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe)" project-jdk-type="Python SDK" />
      <component name="PropertiesComponent">
        <property name="project.structure.last.edited" value="Project" />
        <property name="project.structure.proportion" value="0.15" />
        <property name="project.structure.side.proportion" value="0.2" />
        <property name="settings.editor.selected.configurable" value="reference.projectsettings.compiler.javacompiler" />
        <property name="nodejs_interpreter_path" value="C:/Program Files/nodejs/node" />
        <property name="JavaScriptPreferStrict" value="false" />
        <property name="JavaScriptWeakerCompletionTypeGuess" value="true" />
      </component>
```

Comment: Use File | Default Project Structure or open the default structure settings from the Welcome screen to change the default SDK used for the new projects. You can also remove the old SDK from this dialog.

Comment: It didn't help. By the way i have removed the component and PPython path and now shows "No SDK" up, i can only choose the Java SDK manual per project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with the help of @Russiancold's answer. I edited the project.default.xml file.

first removed this component

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="Python 3.5.2 (C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe)" project-jdk-type="Python SDK" />
```

then added this component

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Check project's `.idea/misc.xml` there are some configs of your project. Also check [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and go to `options\jdk.table.xml`. If you won't find anything strange there, then it's better to report this on the [JetBrains Issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

Comment: I have this problem in all projects, not only a specific project. jdk.table.xml seems correct.